# How to get the layer name of the WMS in the legend of the user interface

Tags: wms, layers, legend, mapfile

I have a problem with displaying the name of the layer in the legend of the user interface. I prepare the mapfile and I access with the WMS in my local test interface. When I add it to the user interface, the WMS appears but, the name of the layer does not appear in the caption. Here's my mapfile code

```
LAYER   
    INCLUDE "../shared/ec/ec_getFeatureInfo.map"
    
    NAME "WMS"
    GROUP "Bâtiments"  

    METADATA
        INCLUDE                 "../shared/ec/ec_meta_layer.map"
        "wms_group_title"       "Bâtiments"
        "wms_title"             "Extraction automatique d'empreintes de bâtiments"
        "wms_name"              "automatic_extraction_building_footprint_fr"
        "wms_server_version"    "1.3.0"
        "wms_format"            "image/png"
        "wms_dataurl_format"    "igo"
        "wms_dataurl_href"      "https://ouvert.canada.ca/data/fr/dataset/7a5cda52-c7df-427f-9ced-26f19a8a64d6"
        "wms_dataurl_format"    "text/html"
    END
    
    #MAXSCALE 10000000
    
    CONNECTION "http://cartes.geogratis.gc.ca/wms/automatic_extraction_building_footprint_fr?"
    CONNECTIONTYPE WMS
    TYPE RASTER
    
    PROJECTION
        "init=epsg:4269"    
    END
END
```

- here the display of the WMS to test it on my local server, in the legend the name of the layer appears

[image]

However in the user interface, it does not appear.

There would be a lack of functionality in the mapfile for the name of the layer to appear in the legend?

[image]

Comment: **the problem has been solved**

Comment: Please write an answer for your solution so that other users may be able to benefit from it. It is fine and encouraged to self-answer.